# Getting Access Denied when running `s3cmd info <bucketname>`

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Using s3cmd version 2.3.0 on AlmaLinux, I can download and sync files to a specific bucket with the policy in place. However, when I run s3cmd info s3://bucketname I get:

```
s3://bucketname/ (bucket):
   Location:  us-east-1
   Payer:     BucketOwner
ERROR: Access to bucket 'bucketname' was denied
ERROR: S3 error: 403 (AccessDenied): Access Denied
```

The policy attached to the bucket is:

```xml
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucketname",
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucketname/*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetBucketPolicyStatus",
                "s3:GetBucketPublicAccessBlock",
                "s3:GetBucketTagging",
                "s3:GetBucketWebsite",
                "s3:ListBucketVersions",
                "s3:GetBucketLogging",
                "s3:GetBucketVersioning",
                "s3:GetBucketAcl",
                "s3:GetBucketNotification",
                "s3:GetBucketPolicy",
                "s3:GetBucketObjectLockConfiguration",
                "s3:GetBucketRequestPayment",
                "s3:GetBucketCors",
                "s3:GetBucketOwnershipControls",
                "s3:GetBucketLocation"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucketname",
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucketname/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

This seems like I am missing one or more actions in my attached policy but I cannot figure out what might be missing.

What changes to my policy, or elsewhere do I need to make, in order to use the `s3cmd info` command?

Edit: Adding more information.

Using s3cmd version 2.4.0 gives slightly more information, but still getting Access Denied:

```
s3://bucketname/ (bucket):
   Location:  us-east-1
   Payer:     BucketOwner
   Ownership: BucketOwnerEnforced
   Versioning:none
ERROR: Access to bucket 'bucketname' was denied
ERROR: S3 error: 403 (AccessDenied): Access Denied
```

Comment: Can you see anything in CloudTrail that might hint as to which API calls are being made? Also, is there any particular reason why you are using `s3cmd` instead of the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/)? I notice that `s3cmd` is [rarely updated](https://sourceforge.net/projects/s3tools/files/s3cmd/).

Comment: I would steer clear of `s3cmd`; it just makes the API operations seem confusing when they're really quite straight forward.  [There i no actual "info" command in S3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/service-authorization/latest/reference/list_amazons3.html). No doubt it's doing one of the `GetBucket*` operations but chose to omit the action that it would have got in the S3 access denied response.  You can use a wildcard `s3:GetBucket*` instead of enumerating them